# How should I call Net Use command to disconnect from a remote location?

Tags: windows, command-line, net-use

When I "net use" I see that I have a connection to a remote location:

```
\\fooo.com\boo\zoo
```

but without any device name assigned.

What is the correct way/syntax to disconnect from this remote location by using the net use command?

Answer (score 4):

Call `net use` as you ordinarily would, passing the remote UNC path in place of the usual local drive letter:

```
net use \\foo.com\bar\baz /delete
```